# Animated-gif-lib doesn't work in regular condition

Tags: java, animated-gif

```
            int delayMs = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
            AnimatedGifEncoder e = new AnimatedGifEncoder();
            e.start(Path.of(this.outputPath, name).toString());
            e.setDelay(delayMs);
            saveData.imageList().forEach(e::addFrame);
            e.finish();
```

I check the delays, images, and paths by printing them out.
I'm sure that they are all valid data, but how the gif result doesn't appear on my dir?

I was trying to replace the parameter type of the method-start to FileOutputStream from String,
but it triggered an IOException.